# Memory allocation and indexing tied to SM/core in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have following setup, on top level parent kernel is called:

```
parent_kernel<<<a, 1>>>(...)
```

The only thing it does is calling a sequence of child kernels:

```
child_kernel_1<<<c1, b1>>>(... + offset(blockIdx.x), blockIdx.x)
child_kernel_2<<<c2, b2>>>(... + offset(blockIdx.x), blockIdx.x)
...
```

I need result of `child_kernel_1` to be passed to the `child_kernel_2`. 
Said intermediate result is bigger than any of the inputs, so I can't reuse their memory (at least directly). Also, when combined over `a`, they are big enough to not fit in GPU memory, meaning that bulk pre-allocation prior to `parent_kernel` is not an option.

This left me with `malloc` within `parent_kernel`, which is not a nice thing either, because memory allocation is time consuming, and `a` can be rather large.

At the same time, only limited number of blocks are in execution at the same time, and it doesn't add much overhead to set all allocated chunks to the same size across `a`.

Which makes me wonder, if it is possible to have index tied to SM/core (or analogous), rather than to block? (with the idea that when another block calls under the same SM/core previous must have already finished and it is safe to reuse memory).

Comment: it is certainly possible to manage allocations by SM/block, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362554/minimize-the-number-of-curand-states-stored-during-a-mc-simulation/37381193#37381193).

Comment: @RobertCrovella it misses the level of granularity I am referring to (cores), which is important, because SM is too coerce, and threads can be executed in lockstep leading to unwanted memory access pattern.

Comment: no, there is no way to tie anything at all to a CUDA core.  A CUDA core is approximately a floating point ALU.  There is no guarantee what it will be used for, or which threads or instructions it will be involved in. Given that you have 1 thread per block, there is no possibility for threads to be executed in lockstep.  If you understand the maximum possible occupancy, you should be able to manage allocations per SM, just as the linked answer describes.

Comment: perhaps you don't understand what a CUDA core is.  The closest thing to a CPU core is a CUDA SM.  A CUDA SM does not consist of a number of CUDA cores, in the same way that a CPU consists of a number of cores.

Comment: @RobertCrovella as for the linked answer, you mean determine SM through special register and then manage access to memory chunks associated with that particular SM through atomic locks?

Comment: yes, and no.  Yes, determine which SM I am on through special register.  Then determine which element I am in the SM via an atomic operation (it is not a lock).  Thereafter access to memory proceeds normally.  There is no usage of a lock anywhere.  Coupled with all this, we use a grid strategy that performs multiple operations per block, and choose just enough blocks (choice of `a`)  to be resident.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I initially misunderstood the use of atomic operations for a means to mark memory chunk available / in use, instead of a way to get index.  Thank you for the detailed explanation, it perfectly matches what I looked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's cover the ground already covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362554/minimize-the-number-of-curand-states-stored-during-a-mc-simulation/37381193#37381193) as one possible approach.

The overall concepts are as follows.

1. based on `parent_kernel<<<a, 1>>>(...)`, we have `a` sequences of child kernel launches to perform.  Each item in `a` consists of `child_kernel_1` followed by `child_kernel_2`.  There is a large amount of temporary data that needs to be passed from child 1 to child 2, and we do not wish to preallocate for all `a` quantity of such temporary data.
2. We observe that for each SM in our GPU, there are a maximum number of resident blocks `X` possible; this is a CUDA hardware limit that is queryable at runtime (e.g. `deviceQuery` sample code).
3. Let's suppose we have `W` of these SMs in our GPU (also queryable at runtime).  And let's suppose for each SM, the hardware limit on resident blocks is `X`.  This means that we should only need to provide for `W*X` temporary allocations, and if `W*X` is less than `a`, we may have an avenue to conduct this problem with a reduced temporary allocation size.  (To implement this step correctly, `X` may need to be reduced based on occupancy analysis of the kernel in question.)
4. In order to use this avenue, we will need to limit the total number of blocks we launch so as to only have `X` per SM, i.e. we must launch `W*X` blocks.  Since this is less than `a` (presumably), we must recraft the parent kernel design from:

   ```
   child_kernel_1<<<c1, b1>>>(... + offset(blockIdx.x), blockIdx.x)
   child_kernel_2<<<c2, b2>>>(... + offset(blockIdx.x), blockIdx.x)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < a/(W*X); i++){
       child_kernel_1<<<c1, b1>>>(i, ... + offset(blockIdx.x), blockIdx.x)
       child_kernel_2<<<c2, b2>>>(i, ... + offset(blockIdx.x), blockIdx.x)}
   ```

   (assuming for simplicity that `a` is whole-number divisible by `W*X`, but this can easily be addressed with a limit check)  (Also note, this idea to limit the total blocks isn't absolutely necessary, but it considerably simplifies the per-SM allocation scheme.  See below for an alternate method.)
5. The GPU block distributor will distribute the blocks to each SM, eventually reaching a full load of `X` blocks per SM.  As each block becomes resident on a SM it begins to execute code and does two things first:  A. determine which SM I am on, let's call this `w`, where `w` can take on values from `0` to `W-1`.  B. determine which block number am I on this SM.  This is done with a simple `atomicAdd` and is not a lock in any sense I am aware of that usage.  Let's call the number returned by this `atomicAdd` operation as `x`, where `x` can range from 0 to `X-1`.
6. Each block now has a unique `(w,x)` ordered pair.  With this ordered pair it can select from a set of `W*X` preallocated temporary storage areas.
7. Each block is now performing `a/(W*X)` sequences of child 1 and child 2 launches, and reuses its already selected temporary storage allocation for each 1-2 sequence.

Much of the code needed to realize the above is already in the other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362554/minimize-the-number-of-curand-states-stored-during-a-mc-simulation/37381193#37381193) (method 3).

We can also relax the constraint on the method above where we restrict the total number of blocks launched to how many can be simultaneously co-resident.  Instead, we can keep track of all slots, and make them available as blocks launch and retire.  For this case, each block must signal when it is finished.  Here is a lightly tested example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

const long long DELAY_T = 100000;
// this is used to get one of a set of unique slots on the SM
//const unsigned long long slots = 0xFFFFFFFFULL; // 0xFFFFFFFF assumes 32 unique slots per SM
const int max_num_slots = 32;
const unsigned long long busy = 0x1FFFFFFFFULL;

__device__ int get_slot(unsigned long long *sm_slots){

  unsigned long long my_slots;
  bool done  = false;
  int my_slot;
  while (!done){
    while ((my_slots=atomicExch(sm_slots, busy)) == busy); // wait until we get an available slot
    my_slot = __ffsll(~my_slots) - 1;
    if (my_slot < max_num_slots) done = true;
    else atomicExch(sm_slots, my_slots);}  // handle case where all slots busy, should not happen
  unsigned long long my_slot_bit = 1ULL<<my_slot;
  unsigned long long retval = my_slots|my_slot_bit;
  assert(atomicExch(sm_slots, retval) == busy);
  return my_slot;
}

__device__ void release_slot(unsigned long long *sm_slots, int slot){

  unsigned long long my_slots;
  while ((my_slots=atomicExch(sm_slots, busy)) == busy); // wait until slot access not busy
  unsigned long long my_slot_bit = 1ULL<<slot;
  unsigned long long retval = my_slots^my_slot_bit;
  assert(atomicExch(sm_slots, retval) == busy);
}

__device__ int __mysmid(){
  int smid;
  asm volatile("mov.u32 %0, %%smid;" : "=r"(smid));
  return smid;}

__global__ void k(unsigned long long *sm_slots, int *temp_data){

  int my_sm = __mysmid();
  int my_slot = get_slot(sm_slots+my_sm);
  temp_data[my_sm*max_num_slots + my_slot] = blockIdx.x;
  long long start = clock64();
  while (clock64()<start+DELAY_T);
  assert(temp_data[my_sm*max_num_slots + my_slot] == blockIdx.x);
  release_slot(sm_slots+my_sm, my_slot);
}


int main(){
// hard coding constants for Tesla V100 for demonstration purposes.
// these should instead be queried at runtime to match your GPU

  const int num_sms = 80;
  const int blocks_per_sm = 32;
  // slots must match the number of blocks per SM, constants at top may need to be modified
  assert(blocks_per_sm <= max_num_slots);
  unsigned long long *d_sm_slots;
  int *d_data;
  cudaMalloc(&d_sm_slots, num_sms*blocks_per_sm*sizeof(unsigned long long));
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, num_sms*blocks_per_sm*sizeof(int));
  cudaMemset(d_sm_slots, 0, num_sms*blocks_per_sm*sizeof(unsigned long long));
  k<<<123456, 1>>>(d_sm_slots, d_data);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  if (cudaGetLastError()!=cudaSuccess) {std::cout << "failure" << std::endl; return 0;}
  std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In the first method, I referred to launching `W*X` blocks, but to correctly use that method it would be necessary to do an occupancy analysis.  The number `W*X` may need to be reduced due to the occupancy analysis.  The second method as indicated in the code sample can work correctly for an arbitrary number of blocks launched.