# How can I address unique sections of reused global memory for each active thread block?

Tags: c++, cuda

Note: I am using a GT 740, with 2 SMs and 192 CUDA cores per SM.

I have a working CUDA kernel that is executed 4 times:

```
__global__ void foo(float *d_a, int i) {
   if (i < 1500) {
      ...
      ...
      ...
   }
}

int main() {
   float *d_mem;
   cudaMalloc(&d_mem, lots_of_bytes);

   for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i += 384)
      foo<<<1, 384>>>(d_mem, i);
   return 0;
}
```

Each kernel call reuses the memory allocated to `d_mem` because of memory constraints.

I would like to modify it to be executed from a single statement, like this:

```
foo<<<8,192>>>(d_mem);
```

I want both active thread blocks to access different halves of `d_mem`, though the specific halves are not important, because data is not shared between blocks.

For example, the following is 1 of several desirable access patterns:

1. Block 1: `d_mem[0]` and Block 2: `d_mem[1]`
2. Block 3: `d_mem[0]` and Block 4: `d_mem[1]`
3. ...

While this is undesirable:

1. Block 1: `d_mem[0]` and Block 2: `d_mem[0]`
2. Block 3: `d_mem[1]` and Block 4: `d_mem[1]`
3. ...

Essentially, I want a way to address `d_mem` so that any combination of active blocks access different parts of it.

I thought that addressing `d_mem` with a block's SM ID might work, [but it appears that this ID is not guaranteed to remain the same throughout a block's life.](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#sm-id-and-warp-id)

I also considered addressing `d_mem` with a thread's global ID modulo 2 `(threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) % 2`, but this relies on the blocks being processed in a particular order.

This is mainly relevant to the use of 1 block per SM, but I am also interested in how this could be solved for an arbitrary number of blocks per SM, if possible at all.

Comment: you have some misconceptions, I believe, such as the number of active blocks you are likely to have, and the significance of the variable block ID,  but leaving that aside, everything you need is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59109845/memory-allocation-and-indexing-tied-to-sm-core-in-cuda) or in the previous answer it links to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be

```
foo<<<2, 384>>> or foo<<<2, 192>>>
```

and putting a for loop around the calculations in your kernel. Then you can select the half of memory with blockIdx.x. Even if the two blocks are scheduled on the same SM, it would work. This method also works with more than one block per SM, e.g. (for quarter memory per block)

```
foo<<<4, 96>>>
```

Having only 192 threads per SM is inefficient (better at least 384, even better 512, 576, 768, 960 or 1024). The SM needs to hide latencies and switch active threads. If you get into memory problems by having more than 384 (=2 SMs *192) calculations active at the same time, try to think, whether you could utilize more than one thread for the same work package (value of threadIdx.x + i), threads can easily cooperate within warp boundaries or use shared memory. Sometimes it is beneficial to use more threads just for the part of your kernel, where you are reading and writing global memory. Here the largest latencies occur.

So you could call your kernel as

```
foo<<<2, dim3(4, 192)>>>
```

and have 4 threads instead of one. For graphics, those 4 could be the rgba channels or xyz coordinates or triangle corners. They can also change their use throughout the kernel.

As a performance optimization this makes some calculations more complicated.

Your if-statement for the current implementation with one block probably should be

```
if(threadIdx.x + i < 1500)
```